# Python2.7: get html of website, href becomes "javascript:void(0)"

Tags: javascript, python, html, python-2.7

I'm sorry if this is a duplicate but I searched a little bit and found nothing, maybe I just didn't know what to search for.

I think the question tells you everything.

I use Python2.7 to get the html of a website.
After that I want to store some data about that website (such as links etc) and download some Files on that Website (automated with python).

Now I'm facing the problem, that one of the links I want to download has the value: "javascript:void(0)"

Here's my code:

```
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.japanesepod101.com/2006/01/16/survival-phrases-5-taxi/')
html = response.read()
f = open("Workfile", "w");
f.write(html)
```

I don't want to go in to much details but when watching the html code of the Website I have this element:

```
<a class="media-download" download="" data-trackme="downloadaudio,33" href="http://media.libsyn.com/media/japanesepod101/029_S5_011606_jpod101.mp3" data-mode="audio">Download MP3<span class="download-tooltip" style="display: none;"><span class="corner"></span>Right Click &amp; 'Save As'</span></a>
```

In my File that's creted that element is this:

```
<a class="media-download" data-trackme="downloadaudio,33" href="javascript:void(0)" data-mode="audio">Download MP3</a>
```

How can I get the link in my File?

For a beginner (me) with python & websites it looks like the javascript functions weren't called (because it isn't opened in a Browser?), is that the case?

Comment: It sounds like the website might generate its links using JavaScript to prevent exactly what you're trying to do. You'd need to use the JavaScript debugger to figure out how their website does so, before you can replicate it in Python.

Comment: Hmm @JeremyBanks I thought so as well, but I visited the website with JS execution disabled and the links were there. Dunno why the links get munged that way, though - it's possible the website sends different data based on the useragent (so normal browsers get normal HTML).

Comment: I am an idiot. This is a website where I need to login first... .
I'll try to login and post my results, that is, if the question remains...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use selenium which will help load the javascript functions and then provide you the final htmlpage

To install selenium

```
pip install selenium
```

Here is the solution.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('yoururl')
htmlpage = driver.page_source
outputfile = open('workfile','w')
outputfile.write(htmlpage)
outputfile.close()
driver.close()
```